# jquery setInterval creates animations buildup

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, setinterval

I created a gallery using setInterval

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/QYEnY/)

The gallery works great, the only problem is that if someone leaves the page exploring another 'browser tab', coming back to the gallery page, it looks like 
`setInterval()` in combination with the jQuery `.animate()` creates a strange animation buildup.

To make my self clear: when you come back from another opened 'browser tab' to the page - the animation seem like it has cached all the animations and now is trying to compensate all the animations at once.

Please any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be doing `setInterval()` here. You can never assume that your animation will be finished in time for the next interval. Always use setTimeout inside a callback:

```
   function start(){
        interv = setTimeout(function() {         
            counter++;                  
            if (counter === (iN+1)) {
                counter = 1;
            }          
            $('#slideshow').animate({scrollLeft: 922*(counter-1)}, 1000, function(){ 
                     start(); // Apply recursive callback
            });
        }, 2000);         
    }
```

Then later on, use `clearTimeout()` instead of `clearInterval()`

Comment: Anytime bro! Always glad to help when I can :)

Comment: Haha I'm trying to reach my daily cap before then!

Comment: Thanks!  Also found the underlying cause of your animation buildup was a bug in jquery. Read the 1.6.3 release notes.

Comment: !!! yeeeees! I know that (don't remember the #number) seems fixed that bug in 1.7.+ completly (it looks...) That's G.R.E.A.T.™ Finally can build sliders and faders and colossal animations without worries! ;)